# Migrations out of sync

Tags: migration

I am trying to update a craft website.
However this fails.
Looking into the migrations table, there were no migrations where track column is "craft", there were some where the track was "plugin:xx".

So there are migrations trying to run, that have already been applied (but are not in the migrations table). I manually entered the rows for the migrations that were already applied.
Now when doing "craft migrate/all" it lists the craft updates without the ones I entered manually.

But now some of the plugin migrations (that were initially in the database) are also showing up on the "craft migrate/all" list and failing when trying to apply them (since these migration have already been applied before.
e.g. the
[image: migration table]
[image: Migration command]

Is there another place where info about migrations is taken from? Or why are these migrations showing up.

When executing craft migrate/new or craft migrate/up it shows
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For reference: what was missing in the table was the correct pluginId for each plugin migration.